# Searching personal account questions

Tags: support

Is there a way to search for something that exists in just the questions I have posted on Mathematica Stack Exchange?

Comment: Yes, use `user:5183 is:question` as additional search terms. You can find the userID in the link to a user's profile. This should probably be in *Meta* though.

Comment: If you want to search just your own contributions, you can also use `user:me` as a search term. Further syntax: [How do I search?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/searching)

Comment: @Marco, looks like an answer to me. :)

Comment: @MarcoB Awesome! That works just as I needed. It's going to be helpful.

Comment: @MarcoB Even shorter: `user:me is:q`

Comment: @J.M. Good point (-: Converted.

Comment: @halirutan Didn't know about the short form; thanks for pointing it out. I added it to my answer below.

Answer (score 6):

Let me summarize what I said in the comments.

In order to search within a certain user's posts, you can use their **user ID** together with the `user` search key in StackExchange's search. You can get the User ID from the link to the user's profile in any of their posts.

For instance, hovering over David's name at the bottom of his question above shows that his user ID is 5183, so using [`user:5183`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A5183) will return all his posts (questions and answers; the link performs a search on the main MMA site).

The user ID is shared between each site and its *Meta* counterpart, but not throughout StackExchange, so the same user will have different user IDs on e.g. MMA.SE and math.SE.

If you wants to search **your own** contributions, you can also use the simpler form `user:me` or `user:mine` as a search term.

---

You can also differentiate between question and answer posts by using the `is:` tag in search:

- `is:question` or `is:q` for *questions* only
- `is:answer` or `is:a` for *answers* only

Thanks to [halirutan](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/users/187/halirutan) for mentioning the single-letter short forms above!

---

Here are a few examples of search tags that I find myself using very often:

- `created:1d..` will list posts created in the last 24 hours; the function also takes closed ranges, and specific dates.
- `hasaccepted:` (y/n) shows questions that have/do not have accepted answers.

For instance, I recently used the following search string to locate questions from last October that had people had found interesting (score=5 or higher), that were not duplicates, that were still open (`closed:no migrated:no`), that had not been tagged as bugs (`-[bugs]`), but that nonetheless had not received any answers:

```
-[bugs] created:2014-10-01..2014-10-31 is:question 
duplicate:no closed:no migrated:no score:5.. answers:0
```

For further search terms, take a look at this page: [How do I search?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/searching)