# Search for questions with expired bounties

Tags: support, search, bounty

The recent [Meta 1644](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1644/1063), as well as [StackExchange help](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/searching), describes advanced searches.  What terms would be used to search for questions with expired bounties (i.e., bounties created more than seven days ago)?

Comment: I can not find any kind of hook that will allow me to formulate a query to find questions with expired bounties. My conclusion is that it can't be done. Will be happy to be proved wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a a [Data.SE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematica/query/46995/the-bounty-picker-upper) allowing you to do it.

Comment: I think that the version of the query linked in the [current revision](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/1725/1) of the answer simply finds the question which had a bounty and [have no answer](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathematica/query/1582811). I suppose you wanted to include the condition `Posts.Id=Votes.PostId` - then you get [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathematica/query/1582785/the-bounty-picker-upper) which returns more results.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit more complex query which should include also questions which had *multiple* bounties and only *some* of them not awarded. (Such as [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/242143/revisions) - you can see that the bounty which ended on 30 March 2021 - with no winning answer - is listed among the results of the query. The same question had two more bounties - but both of them were awarded to an answer.)

SEDE query: [Bounties awarded to no answer](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathematica/query/1582783/bounties-awarded-to-no-answer) (I will add also a link to a [related conversation in the SEDE chatroom](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/conversation/how-to-get-bounties-awarded-by-a-specific-user).)